# Getting Maxar Premium Imagery in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-3, imagery

When you edit OpenStreetMap you have access to the Maxar Premium Satelite Imagery. That is more recent than other imagery in certain areas.

How can I get Maxar Premium Satelite Imagery as a layer into QGIS?